# LazyColumn fling scroll stops abruptly on some devices

Tags: scroll, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column, zebra-scanners

I have the most simple LazyColumn:

```
LazyColumn {
    items(100) { Text(text = "LazyColumn, row $it") }
}
```

[Most simple lazy column list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Qmm.jpg)

On most Android devices the scrolling behaves correctly and there is a smooth deceleration until full stop when fling scrolling through the list. However, on some devices (in my case Zebra scanners MC18 & PS20 running Android 5 & 9 & 11) the scroll stops abruptly and feels janky as soon as I let my finger off the screen.

Using the old AndroidView RecyclerView works like a charm on every device but I would prefer to go all in with Compose :-)

Any tips how to further investigate this issue and narrow it down would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!